# hgignore glob ** not matching correctly

Tags: regex, mercurial, glob

I have tried the following hgignore files however both times folders expected to be ignored are listed when runnign the `hg status` command

```
syntax: glob

Somefolder/**
```

However Somefolder is still listed when I then run `hg status`

So I then tired this version (which should ignore EVERYTHING)

```
syntax: glob

**
```

However same result from running the `hg status` command.

Comment: Isn't it just a single asterisk?

Comment: I'm not sure it seemed to be indicated from other stackoverflow posts that double ** is to include subdirectories, which I would want also ignored as well.

Comment: Yep just tired both * and ** for the second hgignore (the one that is supposed to ignore everything). No difference in the `hg status` command.

Comment: Did you name the file `hgignore`, or `.hgignore`?

Comment: I named the file .hgignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then, I'm not sure what's wrong with your environment, because what you did should work. It works on mine:

```
santa@samoyed:/tmp/MockProject$ tree .
.
└── Somefolder
    └── Subfolder
        └── ph.txt

2 directories, 1 file
santa@samoyed:/tmp/MockProject$ cat .hgignore 
syntax: glob

Somefolder/**
santa@samoyed:/tmp/MockProject$ hg status
? .hgignore
santa@samoyed:/tmp/MockProject$
```

Comment: Does it matter that the files are from an old revision?

Comment: Ah. Yes. If the file(s) you're trying to ignore is already in the repository history and it has been changed, it'll still show up as an uncommitted change.

Comment: If you delete it first, then commit, then commit your new .hgignore file, it'll start getting ignored. But its past existence in the repository history is already set.